# Evaluation order for always blocks triggered within always blocks in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I understand that, for 2 always blocks with the same trigger, their order of evaluation is completely unpredictable.

However, suppose I have:

```
always @(a) begin : blockX 
c = 0;
d = a + 2;
if(c != 1) e = 2;
end

always @(a) begin : blockY 
e = 3;
end

always @(d) begin : blockZ 
c = 1;
e = 1;
end
```

Suppose block X evaluates first. Does changing d in blockX immediately jump to blockZ? If not, when is blockZ evaluated with respect to blockY?

My programmer's instinct thinks of the sequence of events as a stack, where evaluating blockX is like a function call to blockZ and I immediately jump there in the code, then finish evaluating blockX.

However, because we call the active events queue, well, a queue, this suggests blockZ is enqueued at the back of the active events queue, and I'm 100% guaranteed it will be evaluated last (unless there are other triggered always blocks).

There's also the intermediate possibility, where it's neither first nor last but is also evaluated in a random and unpredictable order.

So in this example, are 1, 2, or 3 all possible final values for e, depending on how the compiler is feeling at run time?

Additionally, while I understand, of course, this represents awful style, where might I find the specification for this kind of behvaior?

Comment: Is `always@(a) : blockX begin` valid syntax? I thought it had to be `always@(a) begin : blockX` (in verilog 2001, anyway)

Comment: As you remark, this is awful style - the first block should include `c` in its sensitivity list, either explicitly or via `*` - and then the question becomes moot.

Comment: I think this question is more in the spirit of fully understanding system behavior, than in making actual code.

Like in introductory programming classes, where students are asked to trace through code with (more useful) pointers to pointers and evaluate what the result of some expression will be. That's a bit more applied, but the exercise is pedantic enough to be clear that the intent is strictly pedagogical.

Also, @Eric, thanks for the syntax catch!

Comment: I'm with you, but thought a clarification on why this is bad style would be useful to beginners who come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always blocks are not function calls. See a [recent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/336478/38503) I just gave for a similar question. These blocks are concurrent processes. The LRM only guarentees the ordering of statements within a `begin/end` block. There is no defined ordering between concurrently executing `begin/end` blocks (See Section 4.7 Nondeterminism in the 1800-2012 LRM) So a simulator is free to interleave the statements in any way as long as it honors the order within a single block.

So you are correct that `e` could have the final values 1, 2 or 3 depending on how a simulator decides to implement and optimize your code.